# Using a git repository as a website root folder

Tags: apache, git, github

I want to serve a website directly from a git repository. Obviously, this will make updating the live server very simple - and I'm able to switch back to a previous branch if I have problems with new code.

Are there any security issues?

Do I need to add any directives to apache?

Is there any non-secuity related issues else I should know about?

EDIT : See Kan's answer below - and here is a directive to protect the .git folder as I want to set root folder at top level of the git repos

```
<Files ~ "^\.git">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is only one concern - the `.git` folder. But the git stores it in the repo root only. If you place your web-exposed folder as a subfolder of the repo, it will work great and doesn't require any additional configuration. The file structure will be:

```
myProj -+
        +-- .git
        +-- www-files
        ...
        +-- someStuff
```

So, there is no problem at all to expose the `www-files` from a web server.

There is a [great story](http://www.cgisecurity.com/2009/09/svn-flaw-reveals-source-code-to-3300-popular-websites.html) of using the svn instead...

Comment: So i could also restrict access to any .git folder in the http conf?

Comment: You could of course, but the point is: if you point http `document root` to `www-files` it's not necessary, it's simplifies deployment and configuration.

Comment: Web server never _goes up_ from the document root, so it will not give access to the `.git`.

Comment: I've not got my root folder setup like this and would rather not move it. Could you let me know http directives to protect the .git folder?

Comment: RTFM of your HTTP server. Also, you could move the `.git` directory out, there is `GIT_DIR` environment variable for it. Also, there is no problem at all for the git if you move the folder.

Comment: Found the directive and added to my question

Comment: One thing I don't like about it - you always must remember to add the special http config if something changes (e.g. you have changed web server or moved to a different computer). And there is no easy way to test it automatically.

Comment: Yes - I agree and I'll use your solution for other git repositories. I have a dedicated server for this single website. The httpd.conf setup is very specific and all directives would be moved with the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what technology you are working with, but it may be the case that not everything needs to be deployed to your live web server (e.g. files that get compiled down, debug pages etc).

You may be better investing your time in a step that will automatically create your 'deploy' site from a git repo, which can then be pushed over via FTP.

Comment: FTP will push all files, but `git pull` transfers only changes. It saves a lot of time and traffic. It's nearly always possible to organise a source code so that one folder will be clean from non-live stuff.

Comment: Given current day connections, not sure that it's going to make a serious difference in time/traffic, unless you're updating your site on a really regular basis.  But to each their own.

Comment: I will go for git - as I can quickly switch branches if a release fails. I used rsync rather than ftp when I was using SVN. But thats just another step. Running git pull on the server feels simpler.